# Разлогинить пользователя в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Как настроить авто выход (разлогиниться) в Laravel спустя к примеру 10 мин ?

Answer (score 4):

Время жизни сессии можно редактировать в `config/session.php` (`lifetime`), либо добавив `SESSION_LIFETIME` в свой `.env` файл.

Значение для времени жизни сессии указывается в минутах.